# Google sheets formula to extract 10-digit mobile number starting from 69

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I want to extract the mobile phones from candidates' CVs.

The mobile phone format I want to extract is `69xxxxxxxx`.

The mobile phone formats i come across in the CVs are:

```
69 xxx xxxxx
0030 69xxxxxxxx
+3069xxxxxxxx
69/xxxx/xxxx
```

The following formula works great but it extracts the first 10 digits detected and not the one that starts with `69`.

```
=IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(I252;"\(|\)|\-| "; ""); CHAR(10))); "\d{10}"))
```

Comment: Try `(?:\+|00)?(?:30)?\d{10}`, or `(?:\+|00)?(?:30)?69\d{8}`

Comment: both of them work, thanks! only issue: it also extracts the country code (+30, 30, 0030), but this is not a problem for me.

Comment: See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58604849/3832970). You need to wrap the part you need to extract with a pair of parentheses.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, how can i verify your solution if it is in a comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
=IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(I252;"[-/() ]+"; ""); CHAR(10))); "(?:\+|00)?(?:30)?(69\d{8})"))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ngtVOc/3) and the Google Sheets screenshot below:

[image]

The regex matches

- `(?:\+|00)?` - an optional `+` or `00`
- `(?:30)?` - an optional `30`
- `(` - start of the capturing group (only this value will be returned):

  - `69` -  `69` value
  - `\d{8}` - eight digits
- `)` - end of the group.

You might consider appending `\b` at the end of the regex to avoid matching the 8 digits in chunks of more than 8 digits.

Note that the separator cleaning regex is `[-/() ]+` now, it matches 1 or more `-`, `/`, `(`, `)` and spaces.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your problem is to make use of a regex lookbehind (although I do not know if Google Sheets supports this).

A regex lookbehind matches a pattern, but without including in the result. The syntax for this, with your example, is:

`(?<=69)\d{10}`

The picture below is taken from https://regex101.com/ (which is a super-useful tool when working with regexps).

[image]

[Regex lookahead, lookbehind and atomic groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups) has some more examples of how lookaheads and lookbehinds work.

Comment: Google sheets regex functions use RE2 regex library that does not support lookarounds. At regex101.com, the relevant option is Go (it also uses RE2).

Comment: Ah, in that case my solution is quite useless :|

Comment: As you can yourself see, [your regex throws an error](https://regex101.com/r/PSEeif/1)

Answer (score 0):

all you need is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A&""; "69.*"); "\s|/|\D+"; )))
```

[image: 0]

---

or better:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A&""; "\D+"; ); "69.{8}")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: it works but it also extracts everything after the mobile number

Comment: very nice! the only problem i found in CVs that have an irrelevant 69 before the mobile: eg. Name:XXX, Surname:YYY Address: Street name 69, Mobile: 6944xxxxxx. The output of the Regextract is: 696944xxxx